# xpath find the right number

Tags: xpath

When I right-click and copy XPath this is what I get

```
//*[@id="AssetPreview_0"]/div[7]/div/div[1]
```

The information I want to gather is 119 this is the price of the asset I want to buy.
Whenever i put this into my XML it just returns me N/A I can't seem to figure out how to pick that row of information.

Thanks in advance

[image: Code i try to get information out of]

Comment: How does this relate to software testing? Can you bring more test context around this question?

Comment: please add html as code not as image

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

```
//*[text() = "119"]
```

Comment: did not help xD

Comment: Hm.. Maybe try //*[@class = 'PriceDiff Negative' and text() = '119] or replace text() with @value

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[string() = "119"]
```

try string() method as text() will return only text nodes and not the entire text content